# Output dynamic form content on page after submit using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to output the content of a form on the page underneath it, displaying on the same name. It would be the equivalent of document.getElementById() or jquery equivalent and grabbing the value. I am practicing with some samples I have found online. Below is the code. If someone can show me how to print the details of the dynamic form underneath the horizontal line that would be great.

```js
function fieldModel() {
  var self = this;
  var noTracker = 0;

  self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.removeField = function(dynamicField) {
    self.myFieldList.remove(dynamicField);
  }

  self.addField = function() {
    noTracker++;
    self.myFieldList.push({
      label: "First " + noTracker,
      label1: "Second " + noTracker,
      fname: "var" + noTracker,
      lname: "varry" + noTracker,
      label2: "Textarea" + noTracker,
      texting: "newtext" + noTracker
    });
  }

  self.printField = function() {

    alert(self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([]));

  }

}
ko.applyBindings(fieldModel);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#addVar:hover,
.removeVar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alignRight {
  text-align: right;
}

.displayHeader {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 650px;
}

#action {
  margin-left: 320px;
  border: 4px solid #E3BE8D;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #DAEDE2;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.msg {
  margin-left: 320px;
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: #F6F792;
}

.submit {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #005;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div id="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Test with Knockout</h1>
  </header>
  <!-- /header -->

  <section id="main">

    <form method="post">

      <div data-bind="foreach: myFieldList">
        <p>
          <label data-bind="text: label"></label>
          <input data-bind="attr: { id: fname, name: fname}"><br/>
          <label data-bind="text: label1"></label>
          <input data-bind="attr: { id: lname, name: lname}"><br/>
          <label data-bind="text: label2"></label><br/>
          <textarea data-bind="attr: { id: texting }"></textarea>
          <span class="removeVar" data-bind="click: removeField">Remove</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <p>
        <span id="addVar" data-bind="click: addField">Add</span>
      </p>

      <p class="alignRight">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </p>

      <div data-bind="text: { id: fname, name: fname}"></div>

    </form>

  </section>
  <!-- /main -->

  <footer>
  </footer>
  <!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!--!/#container -->
```

Comment: I've edited your question to include an interactive snippet. This snippet makes it clear that there's still an error logged to the console. You might want to try and fix that to make it easier for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Before we start, here's a version of your snippet that actually runs. You'll see the contents of `myFieldList` logged below the form.

```js
function fieldModel() {
  var self = this;
  var noTracker = 0;

  self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.removeField = function(dynamicField) {
    self.myFieldList.remove(dynamicField);
  }

  self.addField = function() {
    noTracker++;
    self.myFieldList.push({
      label: "First " + noTracker,
      label1: "Second " + noTracker,
      fname: "var" + noTracker,
      lname: "varry" + noTracker,
      label2: "Textarea" + noTracker,
      texting: "newtext" + noTracker
    });
  }

  self.printField = function() {

    alert(self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([]));

  }

}
ko.applyBindings(fieldModel);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#addVar:hover,
.removeVar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alignRight {
  text-align: right;
}

.displayHeader {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 650px;
}

#action {
  margin-left: 320px;
  border: 4px solid #E3BE8D;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #DAEDE2;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.msg {
  margin-left: 320px;
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: #F6F792;
}

.submit {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #005;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <section id="main">

    <form method="post">

      <div data-bind="foreach: myFieldList">
        <p>
          <label data-bind="text: label"></label>
          <input data-bind="attr: { id: fname, name: fname}"><br/>
          <label data-bind="text: label1"></label>
          <input data-bind="attr: { id: lname, name: lname}"><br/>
          <label data-bind="text: label2"></label><br/>
          <textarea data-bind="attr: { id: texting }"></textarea>
          <span class="removeVar" data-bind="click: removeField">Remove</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <p>
        <span id="addVar" data-bind="click: addField">Add</span>
      </p>

      <p class="alignRight">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </p>
      <!-- ko foreach: myFieldList -->
      <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify($data, null, 2)">
      </pre>
      <!-- /ko -->

    </form>

  </section>
  <!-- /main -->

  <footer>
  </footer>
  <!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!--!/#container -->
```

Now, the more general question: "How to view the contents of a dynamic form".

Knockout sort of *expects* you to handle your form submit in the viewmodel. When you add a `submit` binding to the `<form>` element, it cancels the default behavior.

```js
ko.applyBindings({ submit: () => console.log("Submit!") });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="submit: submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your `submit` method will have to know what to post, and retrieve the values. That's two things:

1. Define the data format you want to post to your server
2. Retrieve the values from the viewmodel that are required in this format

In a generic example:

```js
const FormViewModel = function() {
  this.sections = ko.observableArray([]);
};

FormViewModel.prototype.addSection = function() {
  this.sections.push({
    nr: Date.now(),
    // Make an observable value property for
    // keeping up to date with the view
    value: ko.observable()
  });
};

FormViewModel.prototype.submit = function() {
  // Construct the format required by the server
  $.post(this.sections().map(function(section) {
    return { 
      id: "id_" + section.nr,
      val: section.value()
    };
  }));
};

ko.applyBindings(new FormViewModel());

// Mock post
$ = { 
  post: function(data) {
    console.log("posting");
    setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, data), 300);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="submit: submit">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: sections">
    <li>
      <input data-bind="value: value, attr: { placeholder: nr }">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button data-bind="click: addSection">add value</button>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```